# What is the purpose of nav a:focus

Tags: css, focus, nav

Sometimes I see the following code in css.

CSS: 
nav a:focus

HTML:

```
<body>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Ex1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ex2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ex3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ex4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav> 
</body>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/RE006/5ezprru0/

Does that css code serve any purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the `:focus` selector with `input[type]` tags.

For example

```css
#text1{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid gray;

}

#text1:focus{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

`:focus` means is **clicked** and **focused.**